# What safety CFLAGS does the Linux kernel use?

Tags: linux-kernel, compiling, c

I have seen it said that the Linux kernel is built with `-fwrapv` to define signed integer overflow as wraparound, potentially sacrificing a tiny bit of performance in return for preventing the possibility of bugs associated with signed integer overflow being undefined behavior.

What other flags is the Linux kernel built with, for the sake of safety, such as by disabling optimizations based on some variety of undefined behavior?

Comment: Since anyone can tune these CFLAGS ad libitum and build a kernel accordingly, do you mean **upstream's** (kernel devs) **default** CFLAGS ?

Comment: @MC68020 Yes, I do.